# React - Using async for componentDidMoutn

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

Is it OK if I use async in front of componentDidMount like this?

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const key = '11a03b332b43ad4cde5';
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=' + key);
      this.setState({ imgs: response.data });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error happened during fetching!', err);
    }
  }
```

It's working. But I wanted to ask to see if it is ok or is there any drawback to it.

Thanks

Comment: Yep, that's perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's perfectly fine. You are even encouraged to make your http request calls (like your get request with axios there) in `componentDidMount()`, so it only makes sense to be able to use async await there. However keep in mind you can also use `promises` and `.then` instead, which in those cases mean you do not need to add `async` to `componentDidMount()`.